# Trouble creating a working .jar

Tags: java, jar

How can I create a .jar executable from a class file? I found pretty simple instructions online which involve creating a manifest and then condensing it from the terminal.

The *complicating factor*, however, is that the way I programmed this thing, the class file is its own client...it works fine in the compiler but I'm thinking this might somehow change the standard manifest? My program looks roughly like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Schedule implements ActionListener {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Schedule gui = new Schedule();
  }
  public Schedule() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
      //...
    }
    //...
    private class CheckboxListener implements ItemListener {
      //...
    }
  }
}
```

After I compiled this Schedule program, the compiler added a bunch of additional classes to the directory, so in the directory now there's Schedule.class, something called `Schedule$1.class`, `Schedule$CheckboxListener.class` and a bunch of other classes (formatted similarly to `Schedule$CheckboxListener.class`).

Simple put, I'm wondering what my manifest file should look like. Right now, I have:

```
Main-Class: Schedule
```

but this doesn't produce a working .jar file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say "working", what were you expecting?  How are you invoking the JAR file, and what is it doing?  Are you getting error messages?

Comment: When I double-click Schedule.jar I get the following error message:


   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:   Schedule$CheckBoxListener
 at Schedule.<init>(Schedule.java:49)
 at Schedule.main(Schedule.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Schedule$CheckboxListener
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
...

Comment: You have to include those extra classes the javac compiler makes. The $ means inner class.

Comment: Include them in the manifest? Just list them like so: "Main-Class: Schedule, Schedule%CheckBoxListener", etc? Thanks for the replies!

Comment: No, they need to be *inside the JAR file*.  There are files like `Schedule$CheckBoxListener.class` generated, and they need to be included when you build the JAR.

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually put the class files inside the Jar file?  You never mentioned doing that.  See [Creating a JAR File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html), or basically it works like this:

```
jar cf file.jar input-file(s)
```

You can open a Jar file using any program that can open Zip files, like Winzip or 7-Zip.  Or you can just use the `jar` command line tool:

```
jar tf file.jar
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the ticket. Many thanks to you and the others above!

Comment: Great, you're welcome.  Since this answered your question, and since you're new to StackOverflow, please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235